# PulseAudio conflict with ia32-libs?

Tags: apt, pulseaudio

When I was ready to install the PulseAudio server, APT reminded me that this package is conflict with these packages:
 `amarok browser-plugin-gnash browser-plugin-vlc gimp gnash gnash-common goldendict
  ia32-crossover ia32-libs ia32-libs-i386:i386 libgegl-0.2-0 libjack0:i386 vlc
  vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse vlc-plugin-vlsub`

Why are `amarok` and `ia32-libs` in conflict with PulseAudio?
I am confused if I can still use Amarok when I install PulseAudio or not.

I am using Debian Jessie,and with ALSA.

Comment: I've edited your question, it will probably be approved in the queue soon. for when it is, I'd just like to explain why I removed your second question about ALSA vs PulseAudio: on Stack Exchange, we like to have one distinct question per post. otherwise, the answers tend to be responding to mixed things. feel free to open a new question if you still want someone to explain the difference.

Comment: @strugee thank you so much for your modification!I am totally agree with removing the second question.I am not an native English speaker.So I'd be quite appreciate for what you have done to improve the quality of my question.